# Can I publish a web service from Salesforce that doesn't need authentication?

Tags: web-services, salesforce

I need to publish a custom web service from a Salesforce org that allows general public and third party apps to query data from our organization. I have created the web service already, but in order to consume it, Salesforce requires the client to first authenticate with the Partner WSDL, which also makes me require an additional user license.

So the question is: is there a way to publish this web service and allow the third party app consume it without the need of authentication?

In case this is not possible, how can I implement some kind of (cheap) authentication mechanism for third parties, so that they can get access only to the web service in question, and that they can create their own users without the need of manual intervention?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**: 
This is indeed possible (both REST and SOAP) using public sites. See this blog post for example: http://forceguru.blogspot.se/2012/09/creating-public-web-service-in.html

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:
I think that's currently not a feature.

However, you might be able to expose something in a REST style using public sites. In the Visualforce `<page>` tag, you'll be able to manipulate the `ContentType=""` of the response. A URL rewriter class might be all you need to make it a proper REST interface.

Have not tried this.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a good idea. However, we already shared the WSDL definition with some third parties, so we cannot modify the signature now -- we must now use SOAP web serivces.
I read something about an Authorized Website profile, but I didn't manage to use it. Do you know something about it?